# perform expression inside `value` tag

Tags: java, spring

I want to do this

```
<util:set id="datasources" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>#{ '${processors}'.split(',') }</value>
</util:set>
```

where `processors` property is a list `processors=ITEM_1,ITEM_2`. Then I expect to reference that bean in another bean

```
<util:map id="processors" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.util.Set">
    <entry key="processorTypes" value-ref="datasources"/>
</util:map>
```

But it doesn't work - it doesn't split the value and in the end I get all the values inside the `processorTypes` key.

But when I set the `value` directly like this

```
<entry key="processorTypes" value="#{ '${processors}'.split(',') }"/>
```

It works fine and provide me with the set of values for the key.

What is wrong?

Comment: On first look i could suggest to check `value-type="java.lang.String"` since you are expecting a String but passing an array.

Comment: Also note the missing `$` in  `${processors}`

Comment: @MladenSavić well I need a set of strings, but without value-type I get a single value with array type. Ideally I probably need something aking `unwrap` or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things i saw here. First you have processors as String and as map id, thats probably confusing for Spring. Second your SpEL is not defined properly. Here is the proposed solution.

```
    <util:map id="processors" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.util.Set">
        <entry key="processorTypes" value-ref="sourcesSet"/>
    </util:map>

    <bean id="sourcesSet" class="java.util.HashSet">
        <constructor-arg value="#{list.split(',')}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="list" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="ITEM_1,ITEM_2"/>
    </bean>
```